# Swift SWRevealController submenu

Tags: swift, swift2, submenu, swrevealviewcontroller

I'd like to create a submenu in with SWRevealController in Swift. That means if I press a button in in the first slide out menu, another slide out menu appears right next to the first one.
I already managed to create to two slide out menus. One on the right side of the view and one on the left side. I want to have both menus on the same side.

Just like in the third example: [SWRevealController Example 3](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController/tree/master/RevealControllerExample3)
Unfortunatly, there is no storyboard so I can't see how the segues are set etc.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

In the example it looks like there's a view controller called (from within the main slide out menu) which already has another slide out menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for Swift was kindly provided here: [SWRevealViewController Submenu in Swift](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController/issues/593)